# How to make readonly members in powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

How do I make members readonly when I use `Add-Member` cmdlet in Powershell?

Basically, I want to add-member to a `System.Diagnostic.Process` which has a readonly property.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like so:

```
 $p = new-object System.Diagnostics.Process
 $p | Add-member -Name thisisreadonly -membertype scriptproperty -value { 6}
 $p.thisisreadonly #gives 6
 $p.thisisreadonly = 5 #error- Set accessor for property "thisisreadonly" is unavailable.
```

So basically you create a ScriptProperty, with a getter but no setter.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the -secondvalue parameter of add-member is used to provide the "setter".

Comment: Also worth mentioning the `-MemberType` is `ScriptProperty` **not** `-ScriptMethod`, an oversight that lost at least one skimmer of this answer for a few too many minutes.